# Next JS Problem - im getting error when im making yarn dev

Tags: reactjs, next.js

[image]

i have a laravel and nextjs app upon serving my app to yarn dev im runnning into this error on the terminal, can anyone help please.

Comment: in your image, am seeing `warnings` but no `errors`. What is the exact error ?